# Failed to install UWP application

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, win-universal-app, xamarin.uwp

I need help with the scenario below

I have a UWP application that is being installed from a service run by the local system user (user SID S-1-5-18)
The service executes the following command in powershell:

```
Add-AppPackage -Path "C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Windows\App.UWP_2.0.27.0_x64.msixbundle" -DependencyPath "C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Windows\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2.appx", "C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Windows\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2.appx", "C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Windows\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.4.appx", "C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Windows\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx"
```

However, in this process the error is presented:

> The AppX Deployment operation for
> CodeWith7-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith12_2.0.27.0_neutral_ ~
> *3kncj78a7wnxj failed with error 0x80073CF9. The specific error text for this failure is: Add deployment operation rejected in the
> CodeWith7-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith12_2.0.27.0_neutral* ~
> _3kncj78a7wnxj package: App.UWP_2.0.27.0_x64.msixbundle installation request because the account of the Local System is not allowed to
> perform this operation.

I have already done the test and if I change the execution of the service to be performed by a local administrator user the installation is performed. But when run with the local system user it has an error.

I would like to know if anyone knows how to explain to me why I need to be run as an administrator and not by the local system. And if someone chooses to perform in another way to be able to perform the installation with that user.

Note: The application certificate has been added to \ LocalMachine \ Root 
Note 2: When I execute the command related to the installation Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 6a5bae53-546e-0000-2509-99d42d22d701 the return presented is:

> Add deployment operation initiated in a package with the main
> parameter file:///C:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Windows/App.UWP_2.0.27.0_x64.msix
> bundle and dependency parameters
> file:///C:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Windows/Dependencies/x64/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2.appx,
> file:///C:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Windows/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.NET.Native.
> Runtime.2.2.appx,
> file:///C:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Windows/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.4.appx,
> file:///C:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Windows/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx
> and Options 0 and 0. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId =
> 235160 for help diagnosing application deployment issues. The
> application batch signature has been validated for the main content of
> the application batch published by CN = APP STORE, O = APP
> Corporation, C = US. No application packages will be validated until
> they are read. The batch streaming reader was successfully created for
> the
> CodeWith7-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith12_2.0.27.0_neutral_~*3kncj78a7wnxj
> batch. The application package signature has been validated for the
> core content of the application package published by CN = Microsoft
> Corporation, O = Microsoft Corporation, L = Redmond, S = Washington, C
> = US. The payload will not be validated until the files are read. The streaming player was successfully created for the
> Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2_2.2.29512.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
> application package. The application package signature has been
> validated for the core content of the application package published by
> CN = Microsoft Corporation, O = Microsoft Corporation, L = Redmond, S
> = Washington, C = US. The payload will not be validated until the files are read. The streaming player was successfully created for the
> Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
> application package. The application package signature has been
> validated for the core content of the application package published by
> CN = Microsoft Corporation, O = Microsoft Corporation, L = Redmond, S
> = Washington, C = US. The payload will not be validated until the files are read. Application manifest validation warning: the declared
> http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build namespace is
> inapplicable and will be ignored during the processing of the
> manifest. The streaming player was successfully created for the
> Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.4_2.42005.18002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe application
> package. The application package signature has been validated for the
> core content of the application package published by CN = Microsoft
> Corporation, O = Microsoft Corporation, L = Redmond, S = Washington, C
> = US. The payload will not be validated until the files are read. Application manifest validation warning: the declared
> http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build namespace is
> inapplicable and will be ignored during the processing of the
> manifest. The streaming player was successfully created for the
> Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.29231.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe application
> package. Creating Resilience File C: \ ProgramData \ Microsoft 
>
> Windows \ AppRepository 
>
> 8696f38b-b1e3-460d-ae45-5f0cdf55e712_S-1-5-18_1.rslc for the Add
> Operation in the
> CodeWith7-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith12_2.07 Package.
> 0_neutral* ~ *3kncj78a7wnxj. The Add deployment operation in the
> CodeWith7-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith12_2.0.27.0_neutral*~*3kncj78a7wnxj
> package has been removed from the queue and is running for user SID
> 1-5-18. Add deployment operation rejected in
> CodeWith7-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith12_2.0.27.0_neutral*~*3kncj78a7wnxj
> package from: installation request App.UWP_2.0.27.0_x64.msixbundle
> because the Local System account is not allowed to perform this
> operation. The last successful state reached was SharedAppsRedirect. A
> failure occurred before reaching the next OptionalDependenciesHandled
> state. hr: 0x80070057 Add operation failed with target volume C: in
> the
> CodeWith7-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith12_2.0.27.0_neutral*~*3kncj78a7wnxj
> de: (App.UWP_2.0.27.0_x64.msixbundle) error 0x80070057. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing
> application deployment issues. The AppX Deployment operation for
> CodeWith7-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith12_2.0.27.0_neutral*~*3kncj78a7wnxj
> failed with error 0x80073CF9. The specific error text for this failure
> is: Add deployment operation rejected in the
> CodeWith7-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith4-CodeWith12_2.0.27.0_neutral*~_3kncj78a7wnxj
> package: App.UWP_2.0.27.0_x64.msixbundle installation request because
> the account of the Local System is not allowed to perform this
> operation.

Note 3: The machine where the application is being installed has the following characteristics:

- Edition: Windows 10 Pro
  Version: 20H2
  OS Build: 19042.867
  Developer mode is active on the machine

[image: For developer]

[image: About]

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps) before. And and have you enable the system develop model?

Comment: Yes, yes, but I chose to use Add-AppPackage and not Add-AppxPackage. Can you tell me if it interferes?

Comment: Could you try to use `Add-AppxPackage` to deploy your app package ?

Comment: I tried, but presented the same error: Add-AppxPackage: Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF9 [...] installation request because the Local System account does not have permission to perform this operation.

Comment: Please check the system setting, do it enable develop model?

Comment: Yes, it is. I added the image here now

Comment: And have you install the apps certificate before install current app?

Comment: Yes, before running Add-AppPackage I run string.Format("Import-Certificate -FilePath \"{0}\" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\\LocalMachine\\Root", Path.Combine(diretorioInstalacao, item)), with .cer